# How to resolve Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection error while deploying the next.js project on Vercel and Netlify?

Tags: javascript, next.js, netlify, vercel

I'm receiving this error while deploying it on Vercel / Netlify.
Receiving the same error for both Vercel and Netlify while deployment.
Any steps to resolve this issue would be helpful.

Database code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connection = {};

async function connect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    console.log('already connected');
    return;
  }
  if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
    connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState;
    if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
      console.log('use previous connection');
      return;
    }
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  }
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    // useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log('new connection');
  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
}

async function disconnect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
      connection.isConnected = false;
    } else {
      console.log('not disconnected');
    }
  }
}

function convertDocToObj(doc) {
  doc._id = doc._id.toString();
  doc.createdAt = doc.createdAt.toString();
  doc.updatedAt = doc.updatedAt.toString();
  return doc;
}

const db = { connect, disconnect, convertDocToObj };
export default db;
```

Error Screenshot

[image]

Error:

> (`{"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongooseError: The` uri`parameter to`openUri()`must be a string, got \"undefined\". Make sure the first parameter to`mongoose.connect()`or`mongoose.createConnection()`is a string.","trace":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongooseError: The`uri`parameter to`openUri()`must be a string, got \"undefined\". Make sure the first parameter to`mongoose.connect()`or`mongoose.createConnection() `is a string.","    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Checkout your connection string from mongoDB.In your `.env` file  and compare it with the data from the atlas

your **user** is correct ?
your **password** is correct ?
your **cluster** name is the same?
your **database** name is the same?

1a)Make sure that your `.env` is in the root folder!

2)Checkout Network Access IP in mongoDB Atlas. Is it active? If not, establish the new one.

3)If you are using **VPN** turn it off.

4)And lastly => https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables

I hope it helps you! Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Actually i wasn't including env variables while deploying on vercel. that was the problem finally solved.